# Vertically center responsive image in a bootstrap column

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have reviewed all of the existing questions / answers, and still cannot get a working solution, so I would appreciate any comments on my particular code below.

I would prefer not to use hard-coded image sizes (pixel counts) in my code, and I am willing to use a combination of Less, CSS, or Javascript in the solution.

The image should be centered vertically and horizontally within the Bootstrap column, and remain centered even when the screen is resized.

My HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="panel">
                Some content
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="images/myimage.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="panel>
               Some content
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 17):

Here's an option using transform:

```
html,body,.container-fluid,.container,.row,.row div {height:100%;;} /* full height for demo purposes */
.vertical-center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.col-md-2 {background-color:#ccc;} /* just to demonstrate the size of column */
```

http://www.bootply.com/YG8vpg1rIf

Comment: Thanks - in my page, this vertically aligns the center of the image within the center `col-md-2` with the **tops** of the columns on either side (specifically: the top of each panel element in either column). Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a link so I can look specifically at your code? It sounds to me like this is an alignment problem with the panel styles... but it's hard to tell without looking at it.

Comment: I think this only works if all parent elements are `height:100%`

Answer (score 6):

You can overcome the vertical align problem by using css **Flexbox**.

Add the class "vertical_center" to the parent div.

Then add the following css

```
.vertical_center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: If I apply `.vertical_center` to the `<div class="row">` it destroys the responsiveness at smaller screen sizes, i.e. when the columns collapse onto separate rows. Should I apply the `.vertical_center` class somewhere else, or structure it differently? Thank you.

Comment: As you said earlier, you wanted to vertically center the elements of the columns. I think you should put it on the column instead of the row. Would you be able to post a complete fiddle so that I can see what is happening?

Comment: It works for me if i put the `vertical_center` on the `col` and on the `img` I put the class `center-block`

Comment: You should probably mention that flexbox is not supported with IE < 10 and even > 9 there are a lot of bugs.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will solve your problem.
Use following CSS property for making the image vertically centered

`img {  vertical-align: middle;  }`

For horizontal alignment use class name `text-center` of bootstrap along with the other class name of your div if yu have. Like,

`<div class="col-md-2 text-center"> ... </div>`.

It will make the content of the div horizontally centered.